# How can I discover the hostnames for all the machines on my lan?

Tags: networking, avahi

I ssh into the machines on my network using hostname.local. I've forgotten the hostname for one of the machines. Is there a command I can issue from one machine that will broadcast a request for and display all the hostnames for the machines on my lan?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### [`nbtscan`](http://www.unixwiz.net/tools/nbtscan.html)

A good tool to scan all hostnames on a network is nbtscan.

```
$ nbtscan 192.168.1.0/24                                                                                                  
Doing NBT name scan for addresses from 192.168.1.0/24

IP address       NetBIOS Name     Server    User             MAC address      
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
192.168.1.0     Sendto failed: Permission denied
192.168.1.162    CLEMENTINA          <server>  CLEMENTINA          00:00:00:00:00:00
192.168.1.205    CLEMENTINA          <server>  CLEMENTINA          00:00:00:00:00:00
192.168.1.255   Sendto failed: Permission denied
```

- **Note**: This is for NetBIOS, not for mDNS.
- [Official site](http://www.unixwiz.net/tools/nbtscan.html)

You can install it in the Software Center by searching for 'nbtscan', through their website, or via Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install nbtscan
```

Answer (score 32):

### Avahi tools

There also are tools from the Avahi package to list services.

- **avahi-browse** (from [avahi-utils](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/avahi-utils))
  Command line tool that browses the network for any services used by Avahi.

  ```
    avahi-browse -at
  ```
- [**avahi-discover**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/avahi-discover)
  Is a GUI to display all Avahi services available:

  [image]

Comment: Maybe better with [`avahi-browse -alr`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/avahi-browse).