# avahi-browse cannot find all local computers although mDNS is working

Tags: avahi, mdns

I am reading the following procedure:
[How can I discover the hostnames for all the machines on my lan?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/161377/how-can-i-discover-the-hostnames-for-all-the-machines-on-my-lan) .

However, when I tried the command `avahi-browse -av -d local`, it showed the followings, although many more computers (with avahi enabled) are connected in the local network.

```
Server version: avahi 0.8; Host name: mycomputer.local
E Ifce Prot Name                                          Type                 Domain
+ ZZZZZZZZZ IPv4 anothercomputer1 [XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX]     Workstation          local
+ ZZZZZZZZZ IPv4 anothercomputer2 [XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX]     Workstation          local
+ ZZZZZZZZZ IPv4 anothercomputer3 [XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX]     Workstation          local
: Cache exhausted
: All for now
```

In addition, I can connect computers that are not shown above via mDNS, for example, `ssh anothercomputer10.local` works.

How should I do to find all local computers via avahi?

Answer (score 0):

Hiro,

I had the same problem as you when using `avahi-browse` to search for a host on my LAN using mDNS. In my case it was a Raspberry Pi with avahi running. I could ping the Pi with `ping raspberrypi.local` successfully. I could even ssh with the local domain: `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local`.

When I ran avahi-browse initially I was getting a few different hosts on my network (media centres, TV boxes, etc.) **but not** the Raspberry Pi running Avahi.

The solution for me was to edit `avahi-daemon.conf` on the Pi and ensure this option is set to "yes":

```
[publish]
publish-workstation=yes
```

After saving that file I restarted the avahi daemon:
`sudo systemctl restart avahi-daemon`

Now when I run `avahi-browse` on my PC to look for the Raspberry Pi I can see it in the results:

```
E Ifce Prot Name                                          Type                 Domain
+ wlp4s0 IPv6 raspberrypi [xx:xx]               Workstation          local
+ wlp4s0 IPv4 raspberrypi [xx:xx]               Workstation          local
+ wlp4s0 IPv4 otherdevice                             Web Site             local
: Cache exhausted
: All for now
```

Apparently it is a privacy feature of avahi to have the workstation flag set to "no". I suppose it is like why some Bluetooth devices do not make themselves "discoverable".

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. `publish-workstation=yes` worked well.
(I worked with this issue with another workaround, but recently tried this.)